# How to transfer one text file to another one?

Tags: batch-file

I have A.txt file as follow:

```
AAA  Opened successfully.
BBB Cannot connect.
CCC Opened successfully.
DDD Opened successfully.
EEE Cannot connect.
```

How can I use a batch file to generate B.txt as (Only include Cannot rows):

```
BBB Cannot connect.
EEE Cannot connect.
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One-liner

```
find "Cannot" <a.txt >b.txt
```

Comment: Thank you Magoo, It works fine. Do you know how to get rid of the first 3 rows and blank rows and the last row from A.txt to B.txt?

Comment: Yes - it's relatively simple, but that's an unrelated question question so it should be put as another question - together with your coding attempt.